# JQuery Chart + PHP Arrays Bidimensionais

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Esta pergunta é um pouco repetitiva no entanto tentei reformular o código de uma forma diferente.

Então é o seguinte pessoal, eu realizei uma query á base de dados para buscar os valores das tags e da contagem e guardei num vetor bidimensional ambos os campos. Depois fiz json_encode para poder passar este array para uma variável javascript.

```
<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT tag,contador FROM tags";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);

while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
  { 
  $array[][]= $row2["tag"];
  $array[][]= $row2["contador"];   
  }

  $js_array = json_encode($array);
  echo "var tags = ". $js_array. ";\n";  
  ?>
```

Depois no javascript mostrei um alert(tags) para saber se estava funcionando e estava correto! Os valores apareciam desta forma (Exemplo: Technology,4).

```
alert(tags);

// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],

  ['Work', 5],
  ['Newthing', 5],
  ['Newthingz', 5]

]);
  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'Tag Ranks', 'width':450, 'height':400};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Esse código acima do alert irá originar um gráfico com os valores   ['Work', 5],
  ['Newthing', 5],
  ['Newthingz', 5] dentro da variável data. O que eu pretendia era alterar esses valores para o array bidimensional criado anteriormente "tags". Para ficar algo do gênero :

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],

  for (){
  imprimir cada posição do array tags
}

]);
```

Aqui está o código inteiro :

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT tag,contador FROM tags";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);


while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $array[][]= $row2["tag"];
  $array[][]= $row2["contador"];


  }

  $js_array = json_encode($array);
  echo "var tags = ". $js_array. ";\n";



  ?>

  alert(tags);



// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],

  ['Work', 5],
  ['Newthing', 5],
  ['Newthingz', 5]

]);
  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'Tag Ranks', 'width':450, 'height':400};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Comment: Por favor ajudem xD, já estou a tentar resolver este código há horas.

Comment: Nem mesmo o meu professor sabe :/